# In React how to update multiple check box values in to array ?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The form has multiple checkbox a particular question. Is there any option in react to put selected values in to one array like `{questionID: 4, answerValues: [1, 3,4]}` which update based on `onChange`

```
  onChange(event) {
    const question = event.target.dataset.questionId;
    const result = event.target.value;
    let newAnswer = {
      questionID: question,
      answerValues: [result]
    };

    console.log(newAnswer);
    //this.props.updateAnswer(newAnswer);
  }
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/mm49vkx62p

Comment: Create a dedicated property in the component object and maintain an array in it. (not react component `props`, but just a normal js object property)

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a property in `InputCheckbox` to keep track of the `selected` answers, and emit those `selected` everytime a checkbox is ticked:

```
class InputCheckbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.selected = {};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event, optionID) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.selected[optionID] = true;
    } else {
      delete this.selected[optionID];
    }
    this.props.onChange({
      questionID: this.props.questionID,
      answerValues: Object.keys(this.selected)
    });
  }
```

In the `render()`:

```
        <input
          name={name}
          id={`${name}-${option.id}`}
          type="checkbox"
          value={option.id}
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, option.id)} // important
```

In the form, the `event` parameter would now contain (from `this.props.onChange()` above) something like:

```
    {
      questionID: 4,
      answerValues: [1,2,5]
    }
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/21zk2xy42n?module=%2Fsrc%2FInputCheckbox.js

JSKY, there are other ways of doing this (like keeping the selected array in the parent and passing it down to the child, and the child, upon tick, just emit the change event). That was just one of many possible approaches.

Comment: There is really no reason to have state: 1) it's not used in `render` 2) running `setState` would trigger another useless re-render cycle. Just a `this.selected` property would suffice.

Comment: Hum, I think I understand what you mean (I think I saw it coming, I'm not sure). I will try to modify it. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: There you go, I think I did it. What do you think, @zerkms ?

Comment: Yep, that would do. I personally would use the ES2015 `Set`, but the difference is marginal and is a matter of taste.

Comment: I see, I know about it, but never actually used it. Will look into it. Thanks a lot, this has been a useful question! TIL!